# What does CGPointApplyAffineTransform translate into in Monotouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios, core-graphics

I'm missing `CGPointApplyAffineTransform(CGPoint, CGAffineTransform)` in Monotouch.
Any ideas how to convert this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CGPointApplyAffineTransform](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPointApplyAffineTransform) should map to:

```
public PointF MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGAffineTransform.TransformPoint (PointF point);
```

Comment: I don't find that. It is unknown. Can you give an example how one PointF would transform into another PointF by using your method? I can then check if that builds.

Comment: Sorry I mis-pasted to get the namespace (and deleted the `CGAffineTransform` type in the process).

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
CGPoint newPoint = new CGPoint (0, 0);
newPoint = View.Transform.TransformPoint(newPoint);
```